# Android MD5 implementation crashes

Tags: java, android, md5

Whenever running the following code in an Android 2.1 environment it crashes. The following code functions to convert a plaintext string into an MD5. String s is hard coded as `test`. It should print the following result: `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

```
package md5.android;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class md5android extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String s = "test";
        String  res = md5(s);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(res);
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    public String md5(String s) { 
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));

            return hexString.toString();

        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))    
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512    
ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863    
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99    
Looper.loop() line: 123    
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]    
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521    
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860    
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618    
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Error log:

http://pastebin.com/dHXHe9SC

Comment: Great, it crashes... How about stack trace? My crystal ball is out of order...

Comment: Log messages will be quite helpful.. please attach you error log also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work fine. Judging from the log, the problem is that your Activity class name does not match what you have declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Android tries to load the Activity `md5.android.Md5androidActivity`, but the actual Activity is `md5.android.md5android`.

Rename your `md5android` class to `Md5androidActivity` and the crash should go away since it will then match what you have in your manifest.

Comment: I've renamed the class to Md5androidActivity and it still crashes. This same md5 class crashes the project if I insert it into another project (one that would otherwise work fine).

Comment: What does the stack trace of the crash look like after you have fixed the manifest problem? If you still get "Unable to instantiate activity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException", what does your manifest look like?